# WebService call in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I'm developing simple application in WPF with MVVM Light Toolkit. I have two views:

- HomeView (default)
- CustomersView

This is part of the MainViewModel class:

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        CurrentViewModel = Bootstrapper.Instance.Container.Resolve<HomeViewModel>();
    }

    private void ExecuteShowCustomersCommand()
    {
        CurrentViewModel = Bootstrapper.Instance.Container.Resolve<CustomersViewModel>();
    }
```

In CustomerViewModel I have property:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Customers> Customers
    {
        get { return _customers; }
        set
        {
            if (_customers == value) return;
            _customers = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(CustomersPropertyName);
        }
    }
```

And my question is, when I should call the web service to get customers data? In CustomerViewModel constructor?

Comment: In our applications we put async service call in getter of Customers in the first call when _customers is null. You should not put the logic in Constructor.

Comment: Why should I not put logic in constructor?

Comment: Constructor is a very simple method to accept parameters and construct the object. It is better to have minimum logic in it. You can refer to Framework design guidance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229060.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in the constructor of the viewmodel and use a IoC Container to get the instance.

Application start

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MyViewModel>();
```

ViewModel

```
public MyViewModel(IDataService DataService)
{
     Mydata = DataService.GetData(); // Edit: Could also be done in a property with lazy load
}
```

Locator

```
public MyViewModel MyVM
{
    get 
    { 
        return SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MyViewModel>();
    }
}
```